# Interface STM32f4 with LCD16x2

Tags: c, stm32

I write program interface STM32F411vet6 with LCD 16x2 text but when I deliver code to kit it doesn't run. Can someone check my code and find error please? Thank you so much!

Describe:

- void ENEable(void): Wait microsecond to RS pin can receive command.
- void WriteNibble(int8_t data, int8_t flag): Write high nibble(flag = 
  0) and low nibble(flag = 1)
- void LCDCmd(int8_t cmd): Require KIT run command
- void LCDInit(void): initialize LCD.

Code LCD 16x2:

```
void ENEable(void)
{
    HIGH_PIN(EN_PIN);
    DelayMicros(5);
    LOW_PIN(EN_PIN);
    DelayMicros(100);
}

void WriteNibble(int8_t data, int8_t flag)
{
    flag = 4 * flag;
    if(data & (0x80 >> flag))
    {
        HIGH_PIN(D7_PIN);
    }
    else
    {
        LOW_PIN(D7_PIN);
    }

    if(data & (0x40 >> flag))
    {
        HIGH_PIN(D6_PIN);
    }
    else
    {
        LOW_PIN(D6_PIN);
    }

    if(data & (0x20 >> flag))
    {
        HIGH_PIN(D5_PIN);
    }
    else
    {
        LOW_PIN(D5_PIN);
    }

    if(data & (0x10 >> flag))
    {
        HIGH_PIN(D4_PIN);
    }
    else
    {
        LOW_PIN(D4_PIN);
    }
}

void LCDCmd(int8_t cmd)
{
    LOW_PIN(RS_PIN);
    DelayMicros(100);

    WriteNibble(cmd, 0);
    ENEable();
    WriteNibble(cmd, 1);
    ENEable();

    switch(cmd){
        case 0x01:
        case 0x02: 
            DelayMilis(2);
            DelayMicros(250);
            break;
        default:
            DelayMicros(53);
            break;
    }
}

void LCDInit(void)
{
    DelayMilis(15);

    LCDCmd(0x03);
    ENEable();

    DelayMilis(4); //delay 4.1 milisencond
    DelayMicros(100);

    LCDCmd(0x03);
    ENEable();
    DelayMicros(100); //delay 100 microsecond

    LCDCmd(0x03);
    ENEable();
    DelayMicros(100); //delay 100 microsecond

    LCDCmd(0x02);
    ENEable();
    DelayMicros(100); //delay 100 microsecond

    LCDCmd(0x28); // use control: 4 bit, 2 line, 5x8;
    LCDCmd(0x0F); // turn on display, setting, cusor blink
    LCDCmd(0x01); // clear lcd
    LCDCmd(0x06); // set entry mode
}

void SendData(int8_t data)
{
    HIGH_PIN(RS_PIN);
    DelayMicros(5);

    WriteNibble(data, 0);
    ENEable();
    WriteNibble(data, 1);
    ENEable();
}
```

**Delay function:**

Describe:

> void DelayMicros(uint32_t timer): Delay micro second
>   void DelayMilis(uint32_t timer): Delay mili second

```
void DelayMicros(uint32_t timer)
{
    uint32_t count = 0;

    while(timer--)
    {
        count = SystemCoreClock / 1000 / 1000 / 4;
        while(count--);
    }
}

void DelayMilis(uint32_t timer)
{
    uint32_t count = 0;

    while(timer--)
    {
        count = SystemCoreClock / 1000 / 4;
        while(count--);
    }
}
```

I searched the Internet but I couldn't find the reason. I am newbie.

Thank you! Have a nice day!

Comment: "they don't run" is not an error description. What exactly is the error?

Comment: After i deliver code to KIT. I see LCD but it don't show. LCDCmd(0x0F); With this line. I require LCD turn on LCD and blink cusor but I don't see the cursor in LCD.

Comment: We cannot help with hardware/software interfaces like this.  Too much can be wrong that we cannot detect without hands-on with test equipment.  We don't even know if your LCD is powered up:(

Comment: Thank you @MartinJame! I will self study and find error that!

Answer (score 0):

### Did you check the contrast?

Remember that the LCD 16x2 has a pin that adjusts the contrast (pin 3). You should vary the voltage at this pin between 0 to Vcc until you see something in the LCD.

### Othewise...

If this is not the case there are so many things that can go wrong when working on the classic 16x2 LCDs. Bad contact in the pins, inadequate Vcc, bugs in the timing or the correct bit to set. It is hard to tell without the board in the hands. I had to bang my head against the wall for days to get it working the first time, and it was not in the first attempt. I wish you good luck.

Comment: Thank for your comment! But contrast  pin I controled it so I think it will not reason! Do you think my code is right all? I am IT but i am self study. So I cann't find error?

Comment: Really hard to tell without describing the whole setup. Have you tried the check if timing is correct? Try to set a pin high, do a delay of 10 seconds then set low. Check with a multimeter if the timing is actually 10 seconds. It will be easier if you have a LED connected to a I/O port.

Comment: I checked and I believe the delay function is right!

Comment: Try to set the input pins very slowly, checking each input pin at each step and see if it does anything.